# Node.js - Loading Files in Runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, runtime, require

I'm fairly new to Node.js and am having trouble understanding the way to go about loading libraries or files, in **runtime**. 
Apparently, it is a bad idea to load files in runtime using Node.js's native "require" function because it is blocking i/o, and therefore should not be used from within request handlers. So, I'm assuming something like this is to be avoided:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) { 
  var file = require('./pages/'+req.url);
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

**So then is there a way to require files in runtime, in a non-blocking/asynchronous way?**

I don't think it would always be possible to load files in "boot time" rather than runtime because like in the example above, the only way to know what file to load/require is by getting the name through the `req.url` property.

So that seems like the only option. Unless, all the files in the folder are preloaded and then called upon by name, in the callback (By using `fs.readdirSync` or something to iterate through all the files in the folder and compare the gotten files' names to the `req.url` property), but that seems wasteful. "Preloading" all the files in the folder (maybe around 50 files) and then only using 1 of them, doesn't seem like a good idea. Am I wrong?

Either way, I would just like to know if there is a way to require files in runtime in a better, non-blocking/asynchronous way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `require()` is generally used for caching modules or configuration files before most of your application runs. You can think of using `require()` somewhat like this:

```
var file = fs.readFileSync('/path');

// depending on the file type
eval(file);
JSON.parse(file);
```

The reason it is done this way is so that dependencies are loaded in order. If you want to read a file after initializing the application, you should use a asynchronous read, and respond in the callback like this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('./pages/' + req.url, function(err, data) {
    res.end(data);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

If you needed to check if a file existed, then you could use `fs.stat()` to check the existence of a file, rather than querying the directory.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var file = './pages/' + req.url;
  fs.stat(file, (err, stats) {
    if (err || !stats.isFile()) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.send();

      return;
    }

    fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(data);
    });
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great for files like static HTML files, CSS files etc. But what if it's a Javascript file? How should I evaluate the Javascript code that I get from the file? **eval** isn't really a good idea so how should I do it?

Comment: But isn't that considered bad practice? I mean since `require()` is blocking?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it is misleading. I meant, if you have anything to execute, then you should `require()` it at the beginning of the application. That is how `require()` is and should be used. You shouldn't load functions into your application after it has started.

Comment: Oh I see. 
But that is really the problem, that I can't use `require()` inside the request handler, but that's where I need to include the file from. I can only know which file to require by getting the name through `req.url`. But the `req.url` is only accessible inside the request handler. I can't use `require()` anywhere before that because I won't know the name of the file until I get it through `req.url`.

Comment: What type of data are you loading? An entire application?

Comment: Well the code I provided in the question is just an example, but I was actually trying to make an MVC type of application. The data I'm loading is a controller file. A controller file does usually have quite a few functions/logic written in it, I guess.

Comment: If that's what you're looking for, then it isn't really possible. There once was an asynchronous `require()`, but it was seldom used and eventually removed. However, you could fork the main process and run code in another process. There are also modules which do similar things to `eval()`, such as the `vm` module, `vm.runInNewContext()` and `vm.runInThisContext()`.

Comment: @hexacyanide your comment about vm should be an answer, and accepted one at that.